# imeOptions="actionNext" doesn't move to next EditText but focuses

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

I have `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` for "enter pin" `EditText`

and `android:imeOptions="actionDone"` for "repeat pin" `EditText`

But when it's focused on "enter pin" and I press next button on keyboard it focuses to password eye-icon of the same "enter pin" `EditText` instead of "repeat pin" `EditText`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you try to include `singleLine = true`

Comment: Should I create an answer for this?

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine actually it didn't work, I tested it wrongly, it sill focuses next to eye-icon

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine found solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/68557216/7767664

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution by using `android:nextFocusForward`:

```
...
android:id="@+id/enter_password_edit_text"
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
android:nextFocusForward="@id/repeat_password_edit_text"
...
```